# How to inject service inside a guard Nest js

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I have created a guard for global use. Whenever I am trying to inject my user service into the guard getting this error while compiling - `Nest can't resolve dependencies of the VerifyUserGuard (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the UserModule context.`

My user service is a part of user module and inside the user service I have used  `@InjectRepository(User) private readonly _usersRepository: Repository<User>`

Guard -

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from '@v1/user';
import { VerifyUserDto } from '@v1/user/dto';

@Injectable()
export class VerifyUserGuard implements CanActivate {
    //getting error because of this
    constructor(private _userService: UserService) {}

    async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
        const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest<Request>();
        const requestBody = request.body as unknown as VerifyUserDto;
        console.log(requestBody);

        const user = await this._userService.findOneByEmail(requestBody.email);

        return true;
    }
}
```

User module -

```
import { MailModule } from '@mail';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { User } from './entities/user.entity';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserController } from './user.controller';

@Module({
    imports: [MailModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [UserService],
    exports: [UserService],
})
export class UserModule {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need

- **either** to inject your module or service (with providing if not module) in `AppModule` if you connect your guard
- **or** use `@Global()` decorator for your module with service, e.g.

  ```js
  @Global()
  @Module({
    imports: [MailModule, TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
    controllers: [UserController],
    providers: [UserService],
    exports: [UserService],
  })
  export class UserModule {}
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this It worked for me. Use @Inject Decorator.

```
constructor(@Inject(AppService) private _userService: UserService) {}
```